# Select number between 0 and 1 MDB

Tags: php, ms-access, pdo, unixodbc, mdbtools

I am using mdbtools to connect to a mdb-file and retrieve some data from a table in the mdbfile.

In the table there is a field which contains values like

```
0.17, 0.25, 0.17, 0.50, 0.75
```

I see these numbers when looking at the db with MDB Explorer on my MacBook.
But when I select the same field with a PDO/ODBC connection in PHP this is the value i get;

```
000000000000000.
```

When I look up the field information in MDB Explorer this is the information I get;

- **Type:** Numeric
- **Precision:** 17
- **Scale:** 2
- **Decimal places:** Auto
- **Required:** NO

With values like

```
1.25, 1.3, 1.4, 1.2 ....
```

The value I get in PHP;

```
000000000000001.
```

When I dump the table to a .sql file from MDB Explorer I get values like;

```
3.60 instead of 000000000000003.
```

It seems like when I get the value to PHP it is rounded down, and zerofilled.
Anyone have any suggestions to what might be wrong, and how I could fix this?

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM Sales';
$db = isset($this->connection) ? $this->connection : $this->openConnection();
$se = $db->prepare($query);
$se->execute();

while( $s = $se->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ){
    echo $s['HoursWorked']. PHP_EOL;
}
```

I have also tried to dump the result, but the value is like that as soon as I fetch it.

Here is the connection:

```
new PDO("odbc:DRIVER=MDBTools;DSN=MYMDB;UID=;PWD=;");
```

Comment: Yep, I suspect that it has something to do with your code. It's a shame that you didn't post any of it for us to look at.

Comment: I'll add some code for you, but I don't think that is where the problem lies.

Comment: Here what is? Still don't see code. Just results.

Comment: Just got here @TomCollins